# I'm getting an error while Trying to push in my github

Tags: python, git, github, repository, push

I attempted to clone a Git repository, which contains the main 'master' branch.
Additionally, I created a new branch named 'feature1' within the same repository. Upon switching from the 'master' branch to the 'feature1' branch, I implemented a set of new features. Following the completion of these changes, I performed the following actions:

```
git add .
git commit -m "my_message"
```

this is what i get by doing:-

```
git remote -v
```

```
origin  https://github.com/raghavpain/simplepractice.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/raghavpain/simplepractice.git (push)
```

but when i'm trying to push my change by doing this :-

```
git push origin feature1
```

i'm getting this error :-

```
mohit@mohit:~/okk/git_check/simplepractice$ git push origin feature1
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 335 bytes | 335.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
To https://github.com/raghavpain/simplepractice.git
 ! [remote rejected] feature1 -> feature1 (permission denied)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/raghavpain/simplepractice.git'
```

Comment: `permission denied` You do not have the correct permissions to write to the repository.  Do you own it, or does it belong to someone else?

Comment: Or may be `simplepractice` project does not exist yet-

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm currently learning Git and GitHub, and I have two GitHub accounts. I'm in the process of understanding how to contribute to others' code. I cloned a repository from my main account using my second GitHub account. After adding some features, I'm unable to push the changes. It's important to note that I own this repository on my main GitHub account...can you please tell me how to have correct permissions to write the repository.

Comment: @LMC it does exist this is simplepractice github link https://github.com/MOHITMISHRA1997/simplepractice ..please look at it

Comment: ok but error message says `raghavpain/simplepractice` so you are trying to push to someone else's repository, not yours. To contribute to a project you shoud use the fork feature (not clone), make your changes and issue a [pull request](https://docs.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests).

Comment: @LMC yes first i did fork feature..after that i copied the http url forked from MOHITMISHRA1997/simplepractice....then cloned to my desktop so that i can edit in my vscode

Comment: Remove your remotes pointing to  the wrong repo and add yours.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create your local key (id_rsa.pub) and add it to your gihub, so you can push.

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account